# Objective C MKMapView EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, mapkit

I'm a novice ObjC programmer (started learning last week); I'm having some unexpected results trying to get the lat and long from the centre of an MKMapView.

I have the following method that gets called when the map changes region:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView*)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"------> %@", mapView);
    latLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [mapView centerCoordinate]];
}
```

In the log I'm not getting (null), I'm getting the printout of an MKMapView object; but on the very next line I get an unhandled EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Any help appreciated, and I'd be happy to offer more info if it's requested.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CLLocationCoordinate2D` is not an Objective-C object, it's a C structure. You can't directly convert it to an `NSString` like that.

Try:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D center = [mapView centerCoordinate];
latLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%f, %f)", center.latitude, center.longitude];
```

---

**Edit:** Since you're new to Objective-C, thought you might like some insight into how this problem occurs and why the error message is so non-descriptive.

`[NSString stringWithFormat:...]` takes a format string and an arbitrary number of parameters. It then parses the format string and fills in the parameters as they're needed.

The `%@` token in the format string designates an Objective-C object; i.e. an `NSObject *` or subclass thereof. `NSObject` defines the `description` method that provides an `NSString *` description of the object. `stringWithFormat:` calls `description` on the argument provided for the `%@` token to fill it in the format string.

The result of this is a call is made to `objc_msgSend` with your `CLLocationCoordinate2D` struct to make the `description` call because `NSString` assumes you've provided the right kind of parameter. Then the crash occurs because `objc_msgSend` treats the struct as if it's an `NSObject *` pointer and tries to access memory at a bad location. Hence the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

**Disclaimer:** This is based on my understanding of Objective-C after only a couple of years, so if I'm wrong about anything, feel free to correct me.

Comment: Just got back from lunch; this is a brilliant answer, thanks very much! :)